# Program hangs up and windows can't close

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

One of my clients report that some times the program would hang up.
It cannot be killed using task manager and even windows cannot be closed.
I suspect it is due to a USB viertual serial port problem.

I cannot repeat his case, but the program do hangs during trying to close the serial port.
I am using qserialport from Qt. But I could always close the windows properly without any problem. When I remove the usb serial device, the program can always be closed properly.

Will it be so wrong that even cause the whole OS cannot quit properly?

Comment: If program cannot be killed by task manager, this means it is stuck in the kernel mode. Many USB serial port emulators are buggy and can cause such behavior. Recommend to your clients to use another USB serial port emulator.

Comment: So it could even cause things like: I cannot close the OS?

Comment: Absolutely everything: cannot close the OS, computer hangs, blue screen, reboot etc.